# 505 ошибка wp-bakery

Tags: wordpress

Добавлял блоки на страницу с помощью wp-bakery, все сохранил, все работает. Потом пытаюсь снова зайти в редактор wp-bakery на странице и тут мне выдает ошибку 505.

Что делать??? Изменить страницу теперь никак не могу.

На остальных страницах править могу. А эта даже не грузится, сразу окно выскакивает ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отключите плагин wp-bakery. Все страницы, созданные с его помощью, начнут отображаться в виде текста с шорткодами, примерно так:

```
[vc_row][vc_column][contact-form-7 id="3652"][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

Зайдите в админку проблемной страницы, скопируйте весь текст в текстовый редактор и сохраните. Затем удаляйте ряды `[vc_row] ... [/vc_row]` по одному или группами, сохраняйте страницу, включайте плагин wp-bakery и смотрите на результат. Так вы найдёте проблемный ряд. Его потом надо будет создать заново в визуальном режиме.